# Unable to run phantomJS on karma

Tags: karma-runner

I'm encountered a problem recently with PhantomJS library.

```
$ karma start
```

### Log result:

> Karma v0.13.15 server started at http://localhost:9876/ Starting
>   browser PhantomJS INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected
>   on socket H1vRWOIqgBCUjb_bAAAA with id 36694801
>   ***PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR   TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17: The type of an object was incompatible with the expected
>   type of the parameter associated to the object.   at
>   /Users/farman/.../tests.webpack.js:122637 <-
>   webpack:///~/crypto-browserify/rng.js:14:0***
>
> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (2.21 secs / 0
>   secs)

Module versions:

- OSX: El Capitan 10.11.1
- node: 5.0.0
- Karma: 0.13.15
- karma-phantomjs-launcher: 0.2.1
- Phantomjs: 1.9.18

I've checked the forum, but still not solving the issue:
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/45

Comment: Seeing the same error with a React application after recently updating a few dependencies. (Only mentioning this to point out that it's probably not Angular related.)

Comment: Looks like `crypto-browserify/rng.js` points out the likely cause: "This will not work on older browsers" (which I assume includes PhantomJS- unless you polyfill it)

Comment: Can verify that patching this function to use `Math.random` instead did indeed get rid of the issue for me in PhantomJS but that's not really a viable solution.

Comment: Looks like updating `crypto-browserify/rng.js` to use a `Uint8Array` instead of a `Buffer` also resolves the error (at least in my initial testing)

Comment: FYI https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify/issues/143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`crypto-browserify`](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify/) library is using `Buffer` which is buffer is a modified `Uint8Array`. PhantonJS apparently has a bug that rejects `Buffer` though and that's causing the issue you're seeing.

I've filed an issue here:
https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify/issues/143

You can also temporarily patch this by updating `crypto-browserify/rng.js` to replace this...

```
var bytes = new Buffer(size); //in browserify, this is an extended Uint8Array
```

...with this...

```
var bytes = new Uint8Array(size); //in browserify, this is an extended Uint8Array
```